# Word 2016- How to copy/ paste selected Rich Text Content Control in a protected document- VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code below works successfully to create the parent section titled "General".  However, I have the following question:

1. With the document protected, how do I insert an additional section after (below) the parent section (or the current selected section) and loop it so I could add any number of sections? (The parent section starts with numbered list 'A.', so I want each subsequent section to be 'B.', 'C.', and so on).

What I am trying to do is make it simple for any user to add bullets of information in this template I am creating that is protected to prevent tampering.  This will streamline the process, format and presentation of this template to prevent any number of different users in my organization from inputting several different forms of information and styles of formatting.  I want any user to be able to add as many sections as they need to articulate themselves.

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect "green"
'
With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleUppercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        .ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        With .Font
            .Bold = wdUndefined
            .Italic = wdUndefined
            .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Subscript = wdUndefined
            .Superscript = wdUndefined
            .Shadow = wdUndefined
            .Outline = wdUndefined
            .Emboss = wdUndefined
            .Engrave = wdUndefined
            .AllCaps = wdUndefined
            .Hidden = wdUndefined
            .Underline = wdUndefined
            .Color = wdUndefined
            .Size = wdUndefined
            .Animation = wdUndefined
            .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
            .Name = ""
        End With
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
        .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    End With
'
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
    Selection.TypeText Text:="The CONTRACTOR shall "
    With Selection.ParentContentControl
      .Color = wdColorRed
      .Title = "General"
      .DefaultTextStyle = "02_Body"
      .SetPlaceholderText , , "The CONTRACTOR shall "
    End With
    Selection.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlRichText)
    With Selection.ParentContentControl
      .Color = wdColorRed
      .DefaultTextStyle = "02_Body"
      .SetPlaceholderText , , "[Insert Details]"
    End With
'
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
    Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("General").Item(1)
    With cc
    .LockContents = True
    End With
'
Application.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:="green"

    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please report as 4 separate questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: @John Korchok- I am sorry.  I have edited my question.  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the macro recorder, Word uses the Selection object. To turn it into a generalized macro that can be applied to different documents, you almost always want to substitute the Range object for Selection. Sometimes that takes some serious study, but the result is a faster and more reliable macro.

I'm a big fan of using the program features wherever possible. It's easier to maintain and revise. In your case, you can create a section break that is followed by your preferred numbering style. Then select both the break and the numbered heading and save it as AutoText (**Insert>Quick Parts>AutoText>Save selection to AutoText Gallery**) in the template on which your document is based (most often Normal.dotm).

Then, in code use something like this:

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.AutoTextEntries("Section Break with Numbered Heading").Insert Where:=Selection.Range, RichText:=True
```

There's lots of information that you've left out about how you're using this code and what it's for. Like your request to add "an infinite number of sections". Word (and all other software) doesn't do *infinite*. There are always limits of memory and storage space, so perhaps you could define your requirements a little tighter.

Comment: Thank you sir for your response however, I don't quite understand your section break as it relates to numbering style.  Nevertheless, I have updated my question above with more information on how I am using the code.  Will the ```insertItemAfter``` code work for regular content controls?

Comment: You specifically used the word "Section" in your question. The way to create a section is by inserting a section break. If you actually mean "Paragraph", then you should use that word instead.

Comment: Ah I see.  Thank  you.  But will the ```InsertItemAfter``` code work for regular content controls?

Comment: The title of your post mentions Content Controls, but there's nothing in your question about them. You should start a new thread for your question about them. The InsertItemAfter command is a crutch for working with the Selection object. As I've already mentioned, it's a poor practice to depend on that object. Switch your code to use the Range object instead and it will be faster and more dependable.

Comment: Thanks John.  Sorry.  I'm new at this still so I'm trying to learn the ropes

Comment: Here's a page from Microsoft for basic Range techniques: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-range-objects